# Checkbox in ListView Issue with last position automatically get checked

Tags: android, listview, button, checkbox

I am implementing `CheckBox` in `ListView`. I am facing issue where last position of `CheckBox` automatically get checked whenever we check another `CheckBox`.

Here is the `adapter` i implemented :

```
 private class ListAdapter_cb extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ViewHolder vh;
    CheckboxesPOJO cc = new CheckboxesPOJO();
    List<CheckboxesPOJO> array = new ArrayList<CheckboxesPOJO>();
    boolean[] checkedState;
    private Context context;
    boolean[] checkboolean;
    int pos;
    List<String> answers;
    public ListAdapter_cb(Context c, int early_pos, List<CheckboxesPOJO> arraylist) {
        this.array = arraylist;
        this.context = c;
        this.pos = early_pos;
        checkboolean = new boolean[array.size()];
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        final CheckboxesPOJO obj_bean_downloadplus = array.get(position);
        if (convertview == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.element_cb, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.answer_checkbox = (CheckBox) convertview.findViewById(R.id.answer_checkbox);
            convertview.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
        }

        vh.answer_checkbox.setText(obj_bean_downloadplus.getItsanswer() + "");
        vh.answer_checkbox.setId(position);
        vh.answer_checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                {
                    if ((buttonView.isChecked())) {
                        vh.answer_checkbox.setChecked(true);
                        checkboolean[position] = true;
                        checkedList.add(obj_bean_downloadplus.getNumber() + ":" + obj_bean_downloadplus.getItsanswer());
                        Log.v("", TAG + "obj_bean_downloadplus >> " + obj_bean_downloadplus.getNumber() + ":" + obj_bean_downloadplus.getItsanswer());
                        Log.v("", TAG + "obj_bean_downloadplus >> " + checkedList.toString());

                    } else {
                        vh.answer_checkbox.setChecked(false);
                        checkboolean[position] = false;
                        checkedList.remove(obj_bean_downloadplus.getNumber() + ":" + obj_bean_downloadplus.getItsanswer());
                        Log.v("", TAG + "obj_bean_downloadplus >> " + obj_bean_downloadplus.getNumber() + ":" + obj_bean_downloadplus.getItsanswer());
                        Log.v("", TAG + "obj_bean_downloadplus >> " +  checkedList.toString());

                    }
                }
            }
        });

        vh.answer_checkbox.setChecked(checkboolean[position]);

        return convertview;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return array.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This causes last position of `checkbox` automatically checked and even get its answer saved in `checkedlist` where i need to send only those which are checked.

///======RadioButton=====//
Same problem I am facing in radio group.
Please find below radiogroup adater :

```
  private class RadioGroupAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<SubquesPOJO> arraylist_downloadplus = new ArrayList<SubquesPOJO>();
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    int early_pos;
    List<String> arraylist_downloadplusanswer = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] ansarray;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray_radio;

    public RadioGroupAdapter(Context context, int early_pos, int layoutResourceId, List<SubquesPOJO> arraylist_downloadplus1, List<String> arraylist_downloadplus2) {
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.early_pos = early_pos;
        arraylist_downloadplus.clear();
        arraylist_downloadplusanswer.clear();
        arraylist_downloadplus = arraylist_downloadplus1;
        arraylist_downloadplusanswer = arraylist_downloadplus2;
        ansarray = new String[arraylist_downloadplus.size()];
        mSparseBooleanArray_radio = new SparseBooleanArray();
        Log.v("", TAG + "=arraylist_downloadplus.size()=" + arraylist_downloadplus.size());
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final SubquesPOJO obj_bean_downloadplus = arraylist_downloadplus.get(position);
        View row = convertView;
        MatrixHolder holder = null;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new MatrixHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_misssion);
            holder.group = (RadioGroup) row.findViewById(R.id.answer_radio_group);
            holder.rb2 = new RadioButton[arraylist_downloadplusanswer.size()];
            for (int j = 0; j < arraylist_downloadplusanswer.size(); j++) {
                holder.rb2[j] = new RadioButton(context);
                RadioGroup.LayoutParams params = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setMargins(0, 0, 20, 0);
                holder.group.addView(holder.rb2[j], params);
                Log.v("", "=ansarray[position]=" + ansarray[position]);
            }
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (MatrixHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        holder.txtTitle.setText(obj_bean_downloadplus.getTitle());
        for (int j = 0; j < holder.rb2.length; j++) {
            holder.rb2[j].setText(j + 1 + "");
            holder.rb2[j].setId(j);
            holder.rb2[j].setTag(j + 1);
            holder.rb2[j].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.text_grey_dark));
            //  holder.rb2[j].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckListner_radio(obj_bean_downloadplus, holder.rb2[j]));
           /* if (obj_bean_downloadplus.isSelected()) {
                holder.rb2[j].setChecked(true);
            } else {
                holder.rb2[j].setChecked(false);
            }*/
            holder.rb2[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String ansId = v.getTag().toString();
                    ansarray[position] = "\"" + (position + 1) + ":" + ansId + "\"";
                    Log.v("", "=position:ansId=" + ansarray[position]);
                }
            });
            //  mSparseBooleanArray_radio.put((Integer) holder.rb2[j].getTag(), holder.rb2[j].isChecked());
        }
        return row;
    }

    class CheckListner_radio implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        private RadioButton checkbox;
        SubquesPOJO data;

        public CheckListner_radio(SubquesPOJO data, RadioButton checkbox) {
            this.data = data;
            this.checkbox = checkbox;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                checkbox.setChecked(true);
                String ansId = buttonView.getTag().toString();
                ansarray[position] = "\"" + (position + 1) + ":" + ansId + "\"";
                Log.v("", "=position:ansId=" + ansarray[position]);
                data.SetIsSelected(true);
            }/* else {
                checkbox.setChecked(false);
                data.SetIsSelected(false);
            }*/
            mSparseBooleanArray_radio.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arraylist_downloadplus.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Some of the lines are commented which I had implemented same as  check box but it didnt worked.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class ListAdapter_cb extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ViewHolder vh;
    CheckboxesPOJO cc = new CheckboxesPOJO();
    List<CheckboxesPOJO> array = new ArrayList<CheckboxesPOJO>();
    boolean[] checkedState;
    private Context context;
    boolean[] checkboolean;
    private SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;
    int pos;
    List<String> answers;
    public ListAdapter_cb(Context c, int early_pos, List<CheckboxesPOJO> arraylist) {
        this.array = arraylist;
        this.context = c;
        this.pos = early_pos;
        mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
        checkboolean = new boolean[array.size()];
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        final CheckboxesPOJO obj_bean_downloadplus = array.get(position);
        if (convertview == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.element_cb, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.answer_checkbox = (CheckBox) convertview.findViewById(R.id.answer_checkbox);
            convertview.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
        }

        vh.answer_checkbox.setText(obj_bean_downloadplus.getItsanswer() + "");
        vh.answer_checkbox.setId(position);
        vh.answer_checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckListener());
vh.answer_checkbox.setTag(position);
        vh.answer_checkbox.setChecked(checkboolean[position]);

        return convertview;
    }

    public ArrayList<CheckboxesPOJO> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<CheckboxesPOJO> mTempArry = new ArrayList<CheckboxesPOJO>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
            if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {

                CheckboxesPOJO data = mList.get(i);

                mTempArry.add(data);
            }
        }

        return mTempArry;
    }
    class CheckListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

        private CheckBox checkbox;
CheckboxesPOJO data;
        public CheckListener(CheckboxesPOJO data, CheckBox checkbox) {
this.data = data;
            this.checkbox = checkbox;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                        checkbox.setChecked(true);
                        checkedList.add(data.getNumber() + ":" + data.getItsanswer());

                        Log.v("", TAG + "data >> " + data.getNumber() + ":" + data.getItsanswer());
                        Log.v("", TAG + "data >> " + checkedList.toString());

                    } else {
                        checkbox.setChecked(false);

                        checkedList.remove(data.getNumber() + ":" + data.getItsanswer());
                        Log.v("", TAG + "data >> " + data.getNumber() + ":" + data.getItsanswer());
                        Log.v("", TAG + "data >> " +  checkedList.toString());

                    }

            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return array.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: mList is array in my case?

Comment: it is the orignallist from where you get the data

Comment: Thanks but checked checkboxes got removed whenever I scroll up/down?

Comment: yes you need to set the status of check box in your model class and update the check box in getViewMethod accordingly

Comment: still not working it causes checkboxes to be checked at different position on scroll

Comment: i post another answer please modify your existing code

Answer (score 1):

```
In your Pojo class

CheckboxesPOJO.class

add a new parameter

boolean isSelected;

void SetIsSelected(boolean isSelected)
{
this.isSelected = isSelected;
}
boolean isSelected()
{
return isSelected;
}

and in getView Method you need to implement check for this

 public View getView(final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        final CheckboxesPOJO obj_bean_downloadplus = array.get(position);
        if (convertview == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.element_cb, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.answer_checkbox = (CheckBox) convertview.findViewById(R.id.answer_checkbox);
            convertview.setTag(vh);
        } else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
        }

        vh.answer_checkbox.setText(obj_bean_downloadplus.getItsanswer() + "");
        vh.answer_checkbox.setId(position);
        vh.answer_checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckListener());
vh.answer_checkbox.setTag(position);
if(obj_bean_downloadplus.isSelcetd())
{
        vh.answer_checkbox.setChecked(true);
}
else
{
 vh.answer_checkbox.setChecked(false);
}
        return convertview;
    }

class CheckListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

        private CheckBox checkbox;
CheckboxesPOJO data;
        public CheckListener(CheckboxesPOJO data, CheckBox checkbox) {
this.data = data;
            this.checkbox = checkbox;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                        checkbox.setChecked(true);
data.setIsSelected(true);
                        checkedList.add(data.getNumber() + ":" + data.getItsanswer());

                        Log.v("", TAG + "data >> " + data.getNumber() + ":" + data.getItsanswer());
                        Log.v("", TAG + "data >> " + checkedList.toString());

                    } else {
data.setIsSelected(false);
                        checkbox.setChecked(false);

                        checkedList.remove(data.getNumber() + ":" + data.getItsanswer());
                        Log.v("", TAG + "data >> " + data.getNumber() + ":" + data.getItsanswer());
                        Log.v("", TAG + "data >> " +  checkedList.toString());

                    }

            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }

    }
```

Comment: same thing I am using for radiobutton but it did not worked as I am taking list of radiogroup having dynamic radiobutton horizontally and setting in adapter. But on scroll of list, thjose radiobuttons gets automatically clicked which are not visible in UI and on scroll it gets already clicked.

Comment: you need to set the status of radio button using isselected or not

Comment: like you set the status of check boxes

Comment: yes, but its like list of radio group in listview having dynamic horizontal radiobuttons array in everyrow so it needs like this radioButton[i]. at this time it gives only first radiobutton.

Comment: you can set the status using id

Comment: I have edited the question with radiogroup adater, can you please check it and help me out where I am wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105785/discussion-between-bansi-doshi-and-rohit-heera).